# OpenDDS IDL compiler compiler issue

Tags: ubuntu, idl, ace, tao, data-distribution-service

and i am a little bit stuck tryng to compilea simple IDL file.

```
root@ricardo:/home/ricardo/Desktop/librerias/dds/DDS/bin# ldd opendds_idl 
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb771e000)
**libTAO_IDL_FE.so.5.6a_p14 => not found
libACE.so.5.6a_p14 => not found**
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb76e3000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb75fa000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb75dc000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7432000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb771f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb7406000)
```

as you can see, the compiler doesnt found LibTao and LibAce, but it is set in the PATH:

> echo PATH=/home/ricardo/Desktop/librerias/dds/ACE_wrappers/ace:$PATH
>   PATH=/home/ricardo/Desktop/librerias/dds/ACE_wrappers/ace:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
>   And the enviroment variable is set to:

```
root@ricardo:/home/ricardo/Desktop/librerias/dds/DDS/bin# echo $DDS_ROOT
```

/home/ricardo/Desktop/librerias/dds

Can anyone see what is wrong?, did i miss an step?
Which other enviroment variable a i need to can compile a *.idl File?

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] i was just need to add the following lines:

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ricardo/Desktop/librerias/dds/ACE_wrappers/ace:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Addign the ACE ; and then the TAO Libs:

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ricardo/Desktop/librerias/dds/ACE_wrappers/TAO/TAO_IDL:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Setting the ACE_ROOT and TAO_ROOT enviroment varibeles also using export and pointing the dirs that have the shared libs.